Prove that $\int_0^{+\infty} e^{-t} \sum_{n = 0}^{+\infty} \frac{a_n t^n}{n!} dt = \sum_{n=0}^{+\infty} a_n$ without absolute convergence
I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let $(a_n)$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that $\sum a_n$ is convergent ( but not necessarily absolutely convergent ).
$\displaystyle\mbox{Prove that}\quad
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{-t}\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty}
a_{n}\frac{t^{n}}{n!}\,{\rm d}t =
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$.
I managed to prove this equality in the case of absolute convergence by interchanging integral and sum, but I have no idea how to justify this operation in the case of simple convergence.
I am only aware of Fubini Theorem and Dominated Convergence Theorem that allow me to exchange integrals and sums.
I am also aware of Abel’s Theorem for power series but I have no idea
how to apply it here.


See "Borel summation" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_summation
